# How do I deploy a charm from a local repository?

Tags: juju

I am trying to run the Charm tutorial from the juju documentation by creating a new charm from a local repository. I started by installing the charms from bzr to my local ubuntu 12.04 desktop running in a virtual machine. The new file structure is the following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ find charms/precise/drupal/
charms/precise/drupal/
charms/precise/drupal/hooks
charms/precise/drupal/hooks/db-relation-changed
charms/precise/drupal/hooks/install
charms/precise/drupal/hooks/start
charms/precise/drupal/hooks/stop
charms/precise/drupal/metadata.yml
charms/precise/drupal/README
```

When I install the mysql charm, which was downloaded from the remote charm repository, it works fine. However when I run the following command to deploy the new charm it fails with the following error message:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ juju deploy --repository=charms local:precise/drupal
2012-05-09 10:01:05,671 INFO Searching for charm local:precise/drupal in local charm repository: /home/ubuntu/charms
2012-05-09 10:01:05,845 WARNING Charm '.mrconfig' has an error: CharmError() Error processing '/home/ubuntu/charms/precise/.mrconfig': unable to process /home/ubuntu/charms/precise/.mrconfig into a charm
Charm 'local:precise/drupal' not found in repository /home/ubuntu/charms
2012-05-09 10:01:06,217 ERROR Charm 'local:precise/drupal' not found in repository /home/ubuntu/charms
```

Is there some file missing in the drupal charm directory that juju needs to make the charm valid?

Also, I get the file processing error for the .mrconfig file also when deploying the mysql charm so is there something I need to change there perhaps?

Answer (score 8):

> ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~$ juju deploy --repository=charms local:precise/drupal

This appears to be the problem, you don't need to specify precise in the local: bit, try

```
juju deploy --repository=charms local:drupal
```

On Juju 2.0 and up, you can just specify a path to the charm directory. For example:

```
juju deploy ~/charms/drupal --series trusty
```

Local charms may not have a specific declared series (charms fetched from the store always have an implied series).

This page in the documentation has more references on how to deploy from a local repository:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-deploying#deploying-from-a-local-charm